# Command line script with Python 3 and argparse must have an argument?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

Everyone,

I'm creating a command line script based on Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

This script accepts some options that I'm treating with argparse, but the most important one is just a URL which I don't want to treat with an argument.

This is the way that I want it to work:

```
<command> <url> --<optional_argument_1> <value_1> ... --<optional_argument_N> <value_N>
```

And not like this one:

```
<command> --<url_argument> <url> ....
```

Is there a way to this with argparse?

Comment: You need a positional arg. The very first example in the docs (integers to sum) is of this type. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @Hitobat so I should change integers to strings?

Comment: yes, since I think string is suitable for a url param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there are a kind of argument called "positional arguments" and it solved my problem! :)

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments) is the tutorial that I followed to achieve what I wanted.